# How to use default taxonomy with a mixture of terms and content?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

My site has a structure like this, which seems a natural way to use taxonomy:

Food (term)
  - Fruit (term)
  -- Apple (content)
  -- Pear (content)
  - Bread (content)
  - Cheese (content)

The problem arose when I wanted an top-level overview page of Food. Logically (to me) that would mean showing Fruit, Bread and Cheese since these are the direct descendants of Food. But the default taxonomy term page for Food only shows Bread and Cheese, because it only shows content. It doesn't seem like you can show taxonomy terms in views, so overriding the view was not enough and I ended up doing some jiggery-pokery. As a fan of clean logical simple sites I would rather stick close to the defaults. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace the taxonomy/term/## page with a page view of content in that term and "attach" another view to the header that lists the child "taxonomy terms".

That way you them alongside your content as a browsable tree or as a list of "folders" above the content in that folder.

Comment: I didn't know you could have a view of terms - ta. What you suggest is a workaround though, and would not work in my case. The terms would all have to appear together, and the content all together. But my client has their own particular order that they want things to appear in, and that means mixing terms and content. Thanks though